# Cannot figure out git submodule behaviour

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I had used a library called python-magic to find type of file in my django project . However the way I structure my code I prefer to do relative import. However the library did not seem to have an `__init__.py` file to allow relative import , so i made a fork and added one. However when i pulled code on my server even though .gitmodules had my fork's url
url = git://github.com/dusual/python-magic.git  as the entry it only picked up code till index 
d5fba and not 6a5581a which is commit id ? Please explain to me why was this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a git submodule, you are adding a reference to a specific commit of the submodule project.  I suspect what happened is that you did `git submodule add` before you made your change in your forked repo.  Your submodule link is still refering to the commit before you made any changes.

To update this, navigate into your `python-magic` directory and do

```
 git pull origin master
```

(or substitute origin and master for whatever it is in your case if it is different.)

If you then go back to the root directory of your main project and do

```
git status
```

you should see something like

```
-Subproject commit cb25e84cce2845cf18146223e551f47f33a6ee1b
+Subproject commit 75ef943c355e0f53fb6ee48f1117ba8dfdfe3f58
```

for your submodule, which lets you know that it is now pointing to the newer commit.